# add loading page before angular loads my single page app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

so I have a single page app in angular and it takes some time until all elements are being loaded.

I want to show to user a loading message untill angular will be finished bootstraping (plus angular show an ugly skelton of all the elements and pictures for a split second before it is loaded and I want to save that from the user...).

how can I do that? I preffer to do that in angular js (since my code is written in angular) and *not* in JQuery.

index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>

    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="small-talkz.model.js"></script>
    <script src="components/chat/chatController.js"></script>
    <script src="components/login/loginController.js"></script>


 </head>

 <div ng-app="smallTalkzModel" ng-view>
 </div>


 </html>
```

small-talkz.model.js

```
var smallTalkzModel = angular.module('smallTalkzModel', ['ngRoute']);
smallTalkzModel.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl : 'components/login/loginView.html',
    controller  : 'loginController'
  }) 
  .when('/chat', {
    templateUrl : 'components/chat/chatView.html',
    controller  : 'chatController'
  });
});


smallTalkzModel.factory('sessionInfo', function() {
 var savedInfo = {}
 var set=function (info) {
   savedInfo = info;
 } 
 function get() {
  return savedInfo;
}

return {
  set: set,
  get: get
}

});
```

Comment: You can do this in your controller when you're requesting the data from your service.

Answer (score 0):

For the optimal user experience, you should show the animation as early as possible. My recommendation is that you simply show a full-screen div with a CSS animation inside, then use an angular directive to remove the div once the app is running.

Answer (score 0):

Typically what I do in my Angular apps is I'll create some sort of loading variable. I will set this loading variable to 'true' whenever a new controller is initialized, for example, and I will set it to 'false' when everything has been retrieved / bootstrapped. Using this variable, I can show and hide whatever I want. For example:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.loading = true;
  $scope.data = '';

  $scope.init = function () {
    $scope.loadData()
        .then(function (data) {
            $scope.data = data;
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
  };

  $scope.loadData = function () {
    //...
    return promiseData;
  };

  $scope.init();
});
```

Then in my view I can hide and show anything based on that variable value.

```
<body>
    <div class="loading-spinner" ng-show="loading"></div>
    <div class="my-content" ng-hide="loading"></div>
</body>
```

You can also set this variable to 'true' if you are loading something else in the future and you can show the loading spinner again if you wish.

I hope this helps and gives you some sort of starting point into showing loading screens, etc. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks! I have 2 questions: 1. why do you return a promise from the loadData()?
 2. how do you hide your elements while the spinner animation is loaded?

Comment: @Matoy 1. I was just providing an example of some sort of async-operation to signify some length of time in between the request and the retrieval. You can integrate this however it makes most sense in your app. 2. I'm not sure I fully understand your question, however you can use ng-hide="loading" whenever $scope.loading is set to 'true'. This will hide that element until you set $scope.loading = false.

Comment: Not to steal @developthewebz thunder, but here's a working example of what he said: https://jsfiddle.net/93qzds0v/, minus the promise.

Comment: I updated the fiddle using a $timeout for a better proof of concept.

Comment: OP requested the ability to display a loading animation until angular was "finished bootstraping", but this solution won't display anything until after angular is running.

Comment: @AaronCicali is right. I need something to present (loading spinner animation or something) while the boostrap is being loaded.

Comment: That's why I suggested just making a full-screen div with a CSS animation inside, then *removing* it with angular. That's the phase of your application that you want to show the loading animation for. Just find a nice CSS loading animation, here's a nice site: http://projects.lukehaas.me/css-loaders/